# How to overwrite form method on form created by code?

Tags: forms, methods, axapta

On a form created in AOT you can rewrite methods by right click and overwrite. How can you do the same on the form which are created by X++ code?

For example. How to change close method so it will call *info("close");* before closing on this:

```
form = new Form();
formBuildDataSource = form.addDataSource("Table");
formBuildDesign = form.addDesign("Design");
form.design().caption("Caption");
…
args = new Args();
formRun = classfactory.formRunClass(args);
formRun.run();
formRun.detach();
```

I am using AX2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you will want to execute a predefined method. You can then use the `registerOverrideMethod` method of form controls. This is [explained here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajakedar_ganta/archive/2013/04/23/ax-create-forms-using-classes.aspx).

In the call to `registerOverrideMethod` always provide the third argument, being the object holding the method.

```
formButtonControl.registerOverrideMethod(
    methodStr(FormButtonControl,clicked), //method to override
    methodStr(testClass,testMethod),      //method to invoke
    new testClass());                     //object of class containing method
```

It is of cause also possible to save source to the AOT using class `TreeNode` method [AOTSetSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/memberfunction.aotsetsource.aspx). 
An [example here](http://gatesasbait.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/code-code-to-generate-code-in-dynamics-ax/).

You will need to save the form to AOT and compile before executing with `FormRun`.

Comment: I am trying to use this to overwrite clicked method on button. But I get "Error executing code: FormButtonControl (object), method Clicked called with invalid parameters.

Stack trace

(C)\Classes\FormButtonControl\Clicked" every time. 

public void run()
{
    FormButtonControl button;
    super();
    button = element.design().controlName("button");
    button.userPromptText("Test");
    button.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormButtonControl,clicked),methodStr(ClassName,testMethod),this);
} //the button is right, the label is changed
public void testMethod()
{
    info("test");
}

Comment: My test is on existing form.

Comment: Them you could share the form.

Comment: I try it both on form created by code and than on form created in AOT because example:"This is explained here." is created with form. I created similar thing as in example you give and it does not work. It shows that error I share in previous comment.

Comment: Share your form XPO using pastebin.com

Comment: Test form and test class for hello world try.

Comment: You did not provide the third argument to `registerOverrideMethod`.
Answer updated.